# I found but can't open eclipse.ini (bad parsing)

Tags: macos, java, encoding, eclipse

I know the trick with "show package contents" and I've gone to: $ECLIPSE_HOME/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS

However, the file in there is 'eclipse', rather than 'eclipse.ini'

Furthermore, when I open this file, sublime suggests that this is an application and shows me the hexadecimal values...
When I switch to UTF-8, I can see SOME English but most of it is still garbled...

How to open this file properly (and why it's not .ini like all of the internet says it is?)?

Comment: This should get you going, looks like you might be looking in wrong place.  The eclipse you're trying to open is likely a binary [eclipse ini file not present on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454889/eclipse-ini-file-not-present-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've gone crazy and actually searched for the eclipse.ini file. I've actually found it in: 
/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse

It's amazing how much advice on the internet (including eclipse.org!) points to: 
/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS

It must have been true at some point but perhaps with newer versions, this is not necessarily true anymore, which is why I would like to keep this question and this answer despite the basic mistake - in order to inform other people with the same problem.

Comment: Older versions of Eclipse were not packaged as proper Mac applications and had the eclipse.ini in Contents/MacOS. Versions from 4.5 onwards are proper Mac apps and the ini is in Contents/Eclipse